# How to remove default/locked assembly reference from .NET SDK csproj that is targeting full .NET Framework?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-core

I have a new csproj format project that is using `<TargetFramework>net472</TargetFramework>` (targeting full .NET Framework), which adds default set of immutable assembly references to the project (as shown on the screenshot).

[image: Imgur]

For example, `System.Drawing` is locked and can not be removed.

Yes, I know, if I don't use any classes from `System.Drawing`, it will not be actually referenced.

But still, is there any way to remove/ignore/hide it?

I've already tried `alias` trick to hide it:

```
<Reference Update="System.Drawing">
  <Aliases>excluded</Aliases>
  <Private>false</Private>
</Reference>
```

Did not work.

I have nothing against `System.Drawing` per se — but, what if I have another assembly which exports types with exact same namespaces and names — how to "shadow" existing reference?

Update: csproj looks like this:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
        <TargetFramework>net472</TargetFramework>
    </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: There's no such thing. `<TargetFramework>net472</TargetFramework>` means you have a .NET Full Framework application. You may be using the new `csproj` format but the application is targeting the Full framework

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Updated question, added csproj contents.

Comment: It is a mystery to me why programmers like using the new project format to target .NETFramework.  It was a hack to keep early adopters of .NETCore happy, back when they had to type in a project.json in by hand and msbuild was not ported yet.  It's got a bug-list that's half a mile long, none that they consider fixing.  Just don't bother.

Comment: @HansPassant It's not a mystery at all: there are still tons of projects out there targeting multiple frameworks: `<TargetFrameworks>net472;netcoreapp2.2</TargetFrameworks>`

Comment: Well, that's two mysteries.

Comment: @HansPassant Imagine a proprietary networking library that is used from inside SQL Server CLR stored procedure to communicate with .NET Core service. SQL CLR variant is targeted at `net472`, while .NET Core one targets `netcoreapp2.2` and uses different source code depending on `NETSTANDARD2_0` conditional symbol.

Comment: @HansPassant the new .csproj format is so much better than the old one. for one thing, you can open and modify it without unloading your project. and then it's also so clean and easy to work with compared to the old format. .csproj files can shrink from 200-300+ lines down to just 30-40.

Comment: I keep finding this. I really would like to not have a reference to System.Data or System.Drawing in my logic library...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just in case anybody is still searching for an answer: set the [DisableImplicitFrameworkReferences](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/project-sdk/msbuild-props#disableimplicitframeworkreferences) property to true, then add references to the assemblies that are actually needed.

Answer (score 1):

By default System.Drawing is not referenced in new .net 4.7.2 project.

And if u reference it, u can remove reference when u want it

[image]

Comment: No, that is not my problem. I forgot to clarify, that I am not using .NET Framework project template, it is .NET Core console project that happens to be targeting net472. Updated the question.

Comment: @GeorgeChakhidze there's no such thing. If the target is `net472`, you have a .NET Full Framework project. The only thing that changed is the `csproj` format

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos OK, I've got semantics wrong: **Yes, it is new CSProj format**, targets full .NET Frameworks, and, **most importantly, I can not remove System.Drawing reference.**